# Creating an array of struct without duplicates

Tags: arrays, swift, random, struct

Recently started learning Swift and is now faced with the problem (code below will insert):

I create an array of structure from 3 arrays. When creating an instance of the structure, I need to do it by random (randomElement as I understood) - all 3 parameters must be unique. How do I check for uniqueness in the function?

```
arrayOfHumans = createRandomHuman()

struct Human {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let age: String
    var email: String
}

var arrayOfHumans = [Human] () 
var humans: [Human] = []

let nameA  = ["Tim", "Mike", "Stan"]
let surnameA = ["Burk", "Sims", "Stoch"]
let ageA = ["12", "30", "25"]
let emailA = ["one@live.com", "two@gmail.com", "three@outlook.com"]

func createRandomHuman() -> [Human] {
    for _ in 1...3 {
        if nameA.isEmpty == false {
            let human = Human(name: nameA.randomElement()!,
                            surname: surnameA.randomElement()!,
                            age: ageA.randomElement()!,
                            email: emailA.randomElement()!)
            humans.append(human)
        }
    }
    return humans
}
```

Actual result:

```
first Struct {
    name: Tim
    surname: Sims
    age: 12
    email: three@outlook.com
}

second Struct {
    name: Mike
    surname: Stoch
    age: 25
    email: one@live.com
}

third Struct {
    name: Stan
    surname: Burk
    age: 30
    email: two@gmail.com
}
```

Comment: do you wana keep all 4 attributes unique ?

Comment: Yes, all people are Completely unique

Comment: You should shuffle the arrays and loop through them instead of picking a random element each time if you only want to use each element once.

Comment: You should first define a rule for uniqueness. Name, surname and age are very common to be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to [`shuffle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled) the surname, age and email arrays separately to get a random but unique order.

```
let nameA  = ["Tim", "Mike", "Stan"]
let surnameA = ["Burk", "Sims", "Stoch"]
let ageA = ["12", "30", "25"]
let emailA = ["one@live.com", "two@gmail.com", "three@outlook.com"]

func createRandomHuman() -> [Human] {
    let shuffledSurnameA = surnameA.shuffled()
    let shuffledAgeA = ageA.shuffled()
    let shuffledEmailA = emailA.shuffled()
    var humans: [Human] = []
    for i in 0..<nameA.count {
        let human = Human(name: nameA[i],
                          surname: shuffledSurnameA[i],
                          age: shuffledAgeA[i],
                          email: shuffledEmailA[i])
            humans.append(human)
    }
    return humans
}

let arrayOfHumans = createRandomHuman()
```

Another way is to shuffle the indices

```
func createRandomHuman() -> [Human] {
    let indices = nameA.indices
    let shuffledIndices = (0..<3).map{ _ in indices.shuffled()}
    var humans: [Human] = []
    for i in 0..<nameA.count {
        let human = Human(name: nameA[i],
                          surname: surnameA[shuffledIndices[0][i]],
                          age: ageA[shuffledIndices[1][i]],
                          email: emailA[shuffledIndices[2][i]])
        humans.append(human)
    }
    return humans
}
```

Comment: Since all elements in the arrays are being used only 3 arrays needs to be shuffled:)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Very good point, thanks, I updated the answer

Comment: More efficient would be to shuffle the indices (Not that it matters with just 3 elements)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to ensure that all randomly created humans are different.
If so, the question is when are 2 humans different. This depends on your problem. Thus you as the programmer have to define it.
You can do it by adopting the [`Equatable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable).
As soon as your structs conform to this protocol, you can loop through all previously initiated humans, and check if the new randomly created one is equal to one of them. If so, create a new one.

Comment: In this case, people differ in all respects - Name, Surname, Age and Email. The option with the shuffle I bought!